# maven-compiler-plugin argument string exceeds OS X Terminal limit

Tags: java, macos, bash, maven, javac

I was updating the versions of different dependencies and plugins in the POM of the project I'm working on. One of the updates was bumping maven-compiler-plugin from version 2.3.2 up to 3.1. After doing this, some of the components in the project now no longer builds successfully. The only error given is this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project project-name: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project project-name: Compilation failure
```

When running maven with the -X switch, we also see that there is a huge block of text in the logs. We successfully managed to run this block of text through javac and found that the issue basically boils down to the argument string (ie. the command line options) being too long for the Bash in OS X to process.

```
-bash: /usr/bin/javac: Argument list too long
```

I have tried to gradually increase the version number as well and the problem begins at  maven-compiler-plugin version 3.0.

This is how the plugin is imported in POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There is apparently over 350k characters in the command line options, which the OS X terminal just cannot process. OS X's ARG_MAX is 32 kb, while Linux Ubuntu seems to support 256 kb. The Linux Ubuntu compiles the program with the new version without a hitch, so to me that basically confirms our suspicions.

My question therefore boils down to two things:

1) Can we get Maven to give us a proper error message instead of this huge block of text that needs to be manually run through javac? (Any other errors are cathced as they should be and shown in a proper error message). We have tried a couple of  settings, with no luck.

2) is there a fix that can either a) stop Maven from generating argument strings of this size (*something* obviously happened from version 2.3.2. to 3.1), or b) increase the MAX_ARG on OS X?

Comment: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER might be better suited for a bug report

Answer (score 0):

I used to get these all the time, I developed the habit of moving the M2_REPO to something closer to root, like /java/m2/r by adding

```
  <localRepository>/java/m2/r</localRepository>
```

to my [~/.m2/settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: The string of arguments is actually still too long even after this. The interesting part is that this is apparently only a problem after bumping the maven-compiler-plugin to version 3.0, and is not a problem on version 2.5.1. Another interesting thing is that telling Maven to use an eclipse compiler instead actually solves this problem. On this project however, moving over to using the eclipse compiler is not something we can easily just do.

Answer (score 0):

Removing whole `~/.m2/repository` finally worked for me.